# When do firebase security rules get checked?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Does Firebase enforce security rules when importing a json file? Or when data is entered manually via the Dashboard UI/Firebug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase checks the security rules when you make API calls.  If you have access to the dashboard, you have admin access.

Comment: Indeed: the dashboard runs as an administrator, which means it bypasses data access and validation rules.